# How can I count the numeric value by row of my matrix (not 0 and NA)

Tags: r, matrix, row

I am not good with R and in English.

I want to count the numeric value by row (not 0 or NA). I don't want to sum the value.
Example:

example of the matrix:
[image: example of the matrix]

I want to obtain a column with the count of only numeric value by row

Result
example of the matrix I want:
[image: example of the matrix I want]

I try to use

rowsum (resume_tableau>=1)
rowsum (resume_tableau>=1) (count only the number but for the entire matrix, I want only by row)

Comment: `rowSums(resume_tableau>=1,na.rm=T)` should work.

Comment: How about `rowSums(!is.na(resume_tableau) & resume_tableau!= 0)`? It would be very helpful if you could post some of your `resume_tableau` data here. Maybe paste the result of `dput(head(resume_tableau))`?

Comment: Try posting the actual code in code blocks instead of using pictures/links. This might help your question get answered faster! Help us, help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- cbind('tab 1v0' = c(0, 5678, 15640303, 0, NA, NA), 'tab 1v4' = c(15616593, 0, NA, 48764, NA, NA), 'tab 2v0' = c(0, 45678, NA, NA, 55, 0), 'tab   2v4' = c(5588, 58899858, NA, NA, 0, 5566889992))
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
data <- cbind(data, count = rowSums(data > 0))
```

After reading over the question again, I think this is what you were looking for.